# Changing button title in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, ibaction

Whatsup! I have searched and cannot find an answer.

My problem is with a button I have placed on top of my collection view in storyboard. I have to push the button twice before it updates the button state and calls the functions correctly. I have narrowed down the error, since i am calling `fetchMyPosts()` in `viewDidLoad` it interrupts the state. If i comment out `fetchMyPosts()` from `ViewDidLoad` it works perfect but I need that data called on `ViewDidLoad`. Thanks in Advance. Any help is appreciated.

```
var isSelected: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchMyPosts()

}

@IBAction func myPosts(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if isSelected == false {
   mostLiked.setTitle("My post", for: UIControlState.normal)

        fetchMyPosts()

        isSelected = true

    } else {

        mostLiked.setTitle("your post", for: UIControlState.normal)

        fetchYourPosts()

        isSelected = false
    }

}
```

Comment: i did't understand , please explain what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks for the response. My Problem is with a button on my view controller. I have to physically tap the button twice before the view recognizes the state and starts updating the button titles correctly and calling the data correctly. I believe it is because I am calling fetchMyPosts() in the viewDidLoad().

Comment: are you changing `isSelected ` in `fetchMyPosts`?

Comment: show `fetchMyPosts` method

Comment: Yes, in fetchMyPosts() i have tried isSelected = false

Comment: Can you post fetchMyPosts() method? have you set isSelected in fetchYourPosts() as well?

Comment: @aaron deleted my answer as i misunderstood!

Comment: call fetchMyPosts on a background thread instead

Comment: Sorry I was typing function and uploaded only partly by accident. I did not delete anyones comment on purpose. @ Kamran

Comment: Thanks everyone I actually just figured it out. 

In my viewDidLoad() I went ahead and called the condition in there as well 
if isSelected == false { 
fetchMyPosts() 
isSelected = true
} else {
 fetchMyTopPosts()
 ifSelected = false 
}

Comment: This is more of a side note, but why not just use 

if isSelected { } else { } or if !isSelected {} else {}.   No need to compare isSelected to true or false.